# An error has occurred. 500 JHtmlBehavior::polyfill not found

Tags: joomla

I imported old joomla site via ftp and when I access the administrator page I get this error 
"An error has occurred. 500 JHtmlBehavior::polyfill not found"
 and can't do anything but when I open website it's working..

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue with a client today - and it turned out that it was caused by the usage of IE 8 and PHP 7 which resulted in a Joomla bug. We have written a post about it [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/jhtmlbehavior-polyfill-not-found-fatal-error-on-joomla) and we have just answered a [similar question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/20688/jhtmlbehaviorpolyfill-not-found-error/20944#20944) on the Joomla StackExchange site. Essentially, all you need to do is to use a different browser (Chrome or FireFox).

Answer (score 0):

Here https://www.itoctopus.com/jhtmlbehavior-polyfill-not-found-fatal-error-on-joomla is somewhat like recomendation:

There are no method "polyfill" in behavior.php.

May be it's not very good solution, but mine was put it there:

```
public static function polyfill(){
}
```

into /libraries/cms/html/behavior.php line, say, 28